# Boostrap mobile menu doesn't open as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have read through the posts on this and the videos but I am not to sure what i am doing wrong. The menu in mobile mode does not open. I have looked at other examples but cannot see what i am doing wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE hmtl>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Holla Mohalla - The Forgotten Festival Documentary</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Holla Mohallah">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    
    <!--Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>                                
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                
                <a href=""   class="navbar-brand">Hola Mohalla - The Forgotten Documentary</a>            
          </div> 
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li> <a href="#link 1">link 1</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#link 2">link 2</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#link 3">link 3</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#link 4">link 4</a></li>
            
           </ul>
           </div>
          </div>
            
      
    </nav>
    
    
    
  <!-- Copied from jquery -->  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"</script>    
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

```
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add your jquery.js or jquery.min,js

Comment: Thanks, do you mean in the header? Sorry first time using bootstrap

Comment: you also missed bootstrap.min.js :p

Comment: Ha ha, yeah that was a bit noob. Lol Sorry rushing :)

Comment: sorry. Not scrolling :p well, does it already work? :D

Comment: seey your header type: it should be <!DOCTYPE html> not <!DOCTYPE hmtl> :D lolz

Comment: plus lolz.the script in jquery there's no closing tag: so it should be: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: Definelty <p>Owned</p> ;) thanks appreciated will give it a go now and slow down. appreciated

Comment: Take a look it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253142/bootstrap-navbar-collapse-working-on-computer-not-on-iphone

Answer (score 2):

You missed: jquery.min.js & bootstrap.min.js

link here:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

so, as the default link, you need three links:

1. bootstrap.min.css
2. jquery.min.js
3. bootstrap.min.js

you can place no. 2.3. above `</body>` to get loading faster instead of inside tag `</head>`

This follows is best for practice:

**UPDATED**:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.js">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 1px;" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
..............

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```